# What can you do when you know your answer is wrong, but has the "right" comments below it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, delete

I recently asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737401/330899) on Physics SE. Thinking about it for a while, I thought I had come up with an answer and thus answered my own question. But [Triatticus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23615/triatticus) pointed out how my solution is wrong in the comments of the answer.

Now I am not sure what should I do, that is, should I delete the answer I posted? Or make an edit and if an edit then how? Since I can't delete the answer because of valuable suggestions made by Triatticus in the comment section which may provide insight for anyone who thinks they know the answer just like I did.

Comment: Try to revise your answer. You can say "I originally thought X. However,  that is flawed, as kindly explained by Triatticus. In fact, Y is the case".

Comment: @PM2Ring the thing is that I don't know what that "Y" is.

Comment: Ah. So you need to do further research... I guess you *could* temporarily delete your answer & undelete when you've figured out how to fix it. But IMHO it's ok to leave it visible, so Triatticus (and others) can continue to post helpful comments. Another option is to move your faulty theory into the question itself, and hopefully someone else will be able to clarify things for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring that feels like a good answer to the question